# File cache VS Couchbase

Tags: php, caching, couchbase

I've a scenario where I to render pre-generated HTML. Initially that was being done using file cache. Now that I'm expending it to multiple servers there are possible issues of syncing the cached HTML on all servers. Hence I chose to go with Couch base.

I tried it on one server only by replacing the file cache with Couchbase. The connection to Couchbase (which is installed on local) is persistent. But I'm disappointed to see that it's taking almost 20 times to fetch the HTML from couch base than fetching it from local file. 
Am I doing something wrong? Any recommendations?

Comment: Why not just use memcache ???

Comment: I think couchbase also use memcached behind. Did try that same results

Comment: ??? are you saying memcache is also slow ??? are you servers local or remote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean by 20 times to fetch from Couchbase compared to local file? I would expect a single test to give you a better performance by a file, because it will most likely be in the filesystem cache on the same machine so you're basically doing a memory lookup on the same machine (whereas the other one will connect to another server etc). Try to scale up your test scenario to use more pregenerated files than would fit on your local system and see if you're getting the same scalability when you add more and more files and more and more requests.

Answer (score 0):

Check on couchbase gui, for any miss ratio. It shouldnt take 20 seconds. Try it on memcached and see the results. If its also taking 20 seconds then it could be something else.